# Nesting JSON Dictionary Inside a Key?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, codable

I need to send a request inside a key, expecting it to look like so:

```
 {
  "user": {
    "email": String,
    "password": String
  }
}
```

I am trying to do this via creating a `UserSignupRequest` that has email and password properties and conforms to codable:

```
struct UserSignupRequest: Codable {
    let email: String
    let password: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case email
        case password
    }
}
```

Then creating the parameters for alamofire via:

```
case .signup(let request):
        return ["user": request]
}
```

My logic was this will create the child key value pairs inside a user parent key, however my app fatal errors with errors when trying:

```
urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
```

Im sure the solution is something simple, but I cant quite get it to work! many thanks

Comment: Could you post the rest of that switch? It looks like the problem _might_ be with that case statement, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: theres no rest of it to post, the case is signup and its the only case for now, ive debugged this to the point where its 100% the encoding not the switch

Comment: ok. cool. so when you print the parameters in the debugger, you see what you're expecting to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JSONSerialization

`JSONSerialization` works only with simple types as arrays, dictionaries, strings, numbers, etc.

If you want to use it, then you don't need `Codable`, instead you need function `func toDict() -> [String: Any]` that will convert your `UserSignupRequest` to dictionary.
Then your switch will be look like:

```swift
case .signup(let request):
    return ["user": request.toDict()]
}
```

## JSONEncoder

`JSONSerialization` is old api and if you planning to use `Codable` you need to use:

```swift
urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
```

#### Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

I assume you getting parameters like:

```swift
func parameters(for request: RequestType) -> [String: Any] {
    switch request {
    case .signup(let request):
        return ["user": request]
    }
}
```

So when you pass your parameters in encoder he doesn't know what type to encode.

TO solve we can return not just Dictionary, but specific protocol / type aka:

```
protocol Request {
    func encode(by encoder: JSONEncoder) throws -> Data
}
extension Request where Self: Encodable {
    func encode(by encoder: JSONEncoder) throws -> Data {
        /// since it will be method on specific type, JSONEncoder will know what type is encoding
        return try encoder.encode(self) 
    }
}

struct UserSignupRequest: Codable, Request {
    struct RequestData: Codable {
        let email: String
        let password: String
    }
    let data: RequestData

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "user"
    }
}

func parameters(for request: RequestType) -> Request {
    switch request {
    case .signup(let requestData):
        return UserSignupRequest(data: requestData)
    }
}
```

So now you can do

```swift
urlRequest.httpBody = try parameters.encode(by: JSONEncoder())
```

Comment: that throws `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Comment: thanks, your using `Request Type` but its never defined?

Comment: @jwarris91 `RequestType` it is enum with `case signup(request)`. I don't know how you named this type, so used this name

Comment: ah great ill adapt for my situation and mark this answer if it works out, many thanks, makes sense to me